# How to pre-cache flutter flare animation

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have a flare loading animation which takes time to load. Is there a way to pre-cache the flutter animation?

```
final AssetProvider assetProvider = AssetFlare(bundle: rootBundle, name: 'assets/animations/loop.flr');
cachedActor(assetProvider);
```

Is this the code to cache the actor? 
Then How do I load the cached animation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From https://github.com/2d-inc/Flare-Flutter/issues/180#issuecomment-550584347 
You can use `FlareCacheBuilder` to help you preload flr files for certain sections of your app

code snippet

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.title)),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: FlareCacheBuilder(
                ["assets/Filip.flr"],
                builder: (BuildContext context, bool isWarm) {
                  return !isWarm
                      ? Container(child: Text("Loading..."))
                      : FlareActor(
                          "assets/Filip.flr",
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          fit: BoxFit.contain,
                          animation: _animationName,
                        );
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Is there a way to pre-cache globally?

Comment: I did not found that option, I suggest you can put FlareCacheBuilder in outer scope of your widget tree.

Comment: @chunhunghan What import statements do I need for this to work?

Comment: @I.TDelinquent, import 'package:flare_flutter/flare_cache_builder.dart';

Comment: To achieve a pre-cache globally you can see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a 'global' load to your .flr files the correct way is using `cachedActor` just like you posted.

Let's say you previously executed:

```dart
final assetProvider = AssetFlare(bundle: rootBundle, name: 'assets/animations/loop.flr');
await cachedActor(assetProvider);
```

When you try to use the same `.flr` in a `FlareActor` it will already try to first load this asset from the same cache you populated before.

In [this example](https://github.com/2d-inc/developer_quest/blob/8a7ef09687309c4f48ef040c091fbb44e7b1b909/lib/src/widgets/flare/warmup_flare.dart) the Flare team does exactly this to warmup some files. But notice that they are using an old sintaxe for `cachedActor`.

You can see at the source code [here](https://github.com/2d-inc/Flare-Flutter/blob/3e206c629dcdaff77667fc95663098ea7bc230f5/flare_flutter/lib/flare_actor.dart#L399) and [here](https://github.com/2d-inc/Flare-Flutter/blob/3e206c629dcdaff77667fc95663098ea7bc230f5/flare_flutter/lib/flare_render_box.dart#L287), that when loading the asset it will try at first to load from the cache.

One last thing to finish, `FlareCacheBuilder` uses the same `cachedActor` method internally.